# How to perform grouping in mongodb like lodash chain and groupby

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lodash

I have a lodash function which group and return an array as below

```
  [{ key: '00001',
    amount: 135,
    request: [ false, false ] }]
```

I want to check if the request contains some value. Is there any possibility i can perform this mongoDB aggregate. So far i can only group the data with...
**I am using mongoose**

```
  $group: {
        _id: "$key",
        name: { $first: "$request" },
        count: { $sum: 1 }, 
        totalValue: { $sum: "$amount" }, 
       },
```

The sample document

```
  [{ request: false,
    key: '00001',
    amount: 17,
    __v: 0 },
  { request: false,
    _id: 5f536fb1b05c47f7d87acb8d,
    key: '00002',
    amount: 41,
    __v: 0 },
  { request: false,
    _id: 5f536fb1b05c47f7d87acb8e,
    key: '00002',
    amount: 29,
    __v: 0 },
  { request: false,
    _id: 5f536fb1b05c47f7d87acb8f,
    key: '00001',
    amount: 312,
    __v: 0 },
  { request: true,
    _id: 5f536fb1b05c47f7d87acb90,
    key: '00002',
    amount: 120,
    __v: 0 }]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sample document added

Comment: @turivishal thank you, Is there a way to add a condition to check the request array and if some value is included leave the data?

Comment: I want to query data where both the values in request array are **false**.

Comment: your help is really handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$group` to push request in request field
- `$match` to check condition using `$anyElementTrue`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$key",
      request: { $push: "$request" },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      amount: { $sum: "$amount" }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [false, { $anyElementTrue: "$request" }]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XtnCY3_WhXh)